# Delay Execution Of Script Jquery (or SetTimeOut) BUT when out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

I've read some answers on this problem, but I'm not sure what to do in my case.

I have a function where the idea is it will keep attempting to connect via AJAX, and if it fails it will keep trying again every 5 seconds to submit information.  This is important for a web app I'm developing where the users are offline 50% of the time and online 50% of the time.

The issue is in my current setup, I want to call setTimeOut to delay the execution of the function, but I think because I'm inside another function it has no idea about the location of startAjaxSubmitLoop() function? But when I run my code and check in console, I see millions of connections to my server one after another without a delay.  **It's as if the setTimeout() function delay properties was not working at all but it was still running the function?**

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
function startAjaxSubmitLoop(id,tech_id){
                    //TODO: Make POST instead of GET because of pictures.
                    var request = $.ajax({
                      url: "script.php",
                      type: "GET",
                      data: { }
                    });

                    //If Successfully Sent & Got Response.
                    request.done(function( msg ) {
                        //Sometimes because of weak connections response may send, but the message it worked might not come back.
                        //Keep sending until for sure SUCCESS message from server comes back.
                        //TODO: Make sure server edits existing entries incase of double sends.  This is good in case they decide to edit anyways.
                      $( "#log" ).html( msg );
                    });

                    //If Failed...
                    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                        //Color the window the errorColor
                        //alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                        setTimeout(startAjaxSubmitLoop(id,tech_id),5000);
                        console.log('test');
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setTimeout` incorrectly. You're calling your `startAjaxSubmitLoop` immediately  on the `setTimout` line and passing the result to `setTimeout` instead of your function. [Modern `setTimeout` implementations (es5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) let you pass args to setTimeout as below:

Instead of:

```
setTimeout(startAjaxSubmitLoop(id,tech_id),5000);
```

Use:

```
setTimeout(startAjaxSubmitLoop, 5000, id, tech_id); //call startAjaxSubmitLoop in 5000ms with id and tech_id
```

The standard way of doing this to support older browsers where `setTimeout` doesnt take params is to just wrap your function `startAjaxSubmitLoop`

```
setTimeout(function(){startAjaxSubmitLoop(id, tech_id)}, 5000); //equivalent to above
```

Comment: Thanks worked great! I wasn't aware I was doing that wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: Your third example is missing the semicolon within the callback.  It should be `setTimeout(function(){startAjaxSubmitLoop(id, tech_id);}, 5000);`  makes it look like you copied my code example.

Comment: @ps2goat I posted that before you and the semi will be automatically inserted

Answer (score 1):

two ways to do this:

1) with a callback function:
    setTimeout( function(){startAjaxSubmitLoop(id,tech_id);},5000);

2) with parameters listed after the function name (no parentheses) and timeout period:
    setTimeout(startAjaxSubmitLoop,5000, id, tech_id);